# Guide: what type of chart would be suitable for the given data?

Tags: matplotlib, charts, visualization, presentation

I want to plot a chart for the data but I don't know what type of chart would be appropriate for it.

**Data:** (Please note this is assumed data and is nowhere near the original data)
[image]

**Background:**
I want to plot a time series chart. For each year, latitudes and longitudes are given. For those coordinates, area and temperature in Celsius are also available.

**Goal:**
How can I plot the area and temperature for each latitude and longitude over the period of years? What chart would be most suitable for it?

Comment: Do you specifically want a 2D chart, or can it be a 3D chart?

Comment: @sbottingota A 2D chart.

Comment: Do you want it to be on a map or can "lat,lon" be treated as a categorical value (like 6 sites A, B, C,... to monitor)

Comment: @thmslmr I want them to be treated as categorical data.

Comment: Celsius, Cel**S**ius CELSIUS

Comment: @gboffi Typo..!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps. I didn't fill in the values on the axis or all the data points, but you get the idea.

[image]

Comment: how did you plot these?

Comment: IF you are referring to they Y-axis values, just add values to them and plot them like a normal historgram. But here we just have 2 y-axis so you can give each their own values. Thus Area you can range from 0-350 and Temp you can range from 0-35.

Answer (score 0):

The best chart will depend on your audience and the message you want to send.

I would suggest you take a 2-step process here: First, figure out and decide what your chart should display and look like, second develop the code.

- Is it essential to compare places? (How has Place A developed vs place B)
- Or is it more important to see each place's value differences over time? (Place A in 2000 vs Place A in 2002)
  Or are both of equal importance?
- Are the coordinates all the same for all the years? E.g., always 5 coordinates for places A,B,C,D,E, or is there sometimes A,B,C,D,E,F,G, sometimes A,C,D only..

In any case, I suggest you use the fact that Area and Temperature are perfect chart features. The following chart could be changed to display changes in area and temperature. Tempature could a scale from violet-red, or I suggest to use the felt-temperature by humans, where the maximum is like 45°C (dark red), the minimum like -30°C (very blue). That will however depend on the data.

[image: A heatmap with area and temperature]
Source:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/01/ggplot2-time-series-heatmaps-revisited-in-the-tidyverse/
Originally by https://margintale.blogspot.com/2018/01/ggplot2-time-series-heatmaps-revisited.html

Comment: I want to see the changes in one place over the period of years and the coordinates could change over the period of years i.e. sometimes it could be A,B,C,D,E,F and sometimes A,B,C etc. Could you suggest something?

Comment: I would suggest you use the chart I posted for that. If your area spans many orders of magnitude, e.g. one data point is 10 and another one is 1000, or if your data otherwise follows a weird distribution, it might not be ideal. I suggest the horizontal axis is your time, the vertical your areas, and if for a specific time that area doesn't exist yet in your data, leave it empty. Also, label your area, otherwise its difficult to tell exactly how big it is